# What exactly does /usr/sbin/CreateGroupFolder do?

Tags: mac-osx-server, network-share, osx-leopard

Does "[CreateGroupFolder](http://www.makemacwork.com/share-group-folders.htm)" do anything aside from creating folders in the file-system and setting correct permissions for them?

EDIT: Yep, nothing more, nothing less. As Chealion suggested, I ran it with the verbose flag (doh!) and got:

```
sudo CreateGroupFolder -v

Attempting to create group home directory for group 1026 at "/Groups/FooGroup".
Created directory "/Groups/FooGroup/Documents"
Created directory "/Groups/FooGroup/Library"
Created directory "/Groups/FooGroup/Public"
Created directory "/Groups/FooGroup/Public/Drop Box"
Set ownership to user 1000, group 1026: "/Groups/FooGroup" and all sub-directories and files.
Set permissions to rwxr-xr-x (755): "/Groups/FooGroup"
Set permissions to rwxrwxr-x (775): "/Groups/FooGroup/Public"
Set permissions to rwxr-x--- (750): "/Groups/FooGroup/Documents"
Set permissions to rwxr-x--- (750): "/Groups/FooGroup/Library"
Set permissions to rwx-w---- (730): "/Groups/FooGroup/Public/Drop Box"

Successfully created group home directory for group 1026 at "/Groups/FooGroup".
```

Comment: Have you tried running it verbosely (-v)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateGroupFolder(1)      BSD General Commands Manual     CreateGroupFolder(1)

NAME
     CreateGroupFolder -- Create and populate group directories.

SYNOPSIS
     CreateGroupFolder [-q] [-v] [-f]

DESCRIPTION
     Provides several options for creating and populating group directories.

```
 A list of flags and their descriptions:

 -q       Sets Quiet mode - suppress ouput to console Creates a set of default folders for use by groups
          on the local server with little console messages

 -v       Sets Verbose mode - More ouput to console Creates group directories for groups defined in the
          local server with more console messages

 -f       Force all missing folders to be re-created.  Creates group directories for groups defined in a
          specific server even if they already exist All permissions and ownerships to be returned to
          defaults This option will also change the ownership and permissions on all files within the
          each group's folder hierarchy.  Use this option with care
```

FILES
     /usr/sbin/CreateGroupFolder                   location of tool

Comment: It may be easier to quote the important bits and the link to the man page instead of copying and pasting it here. http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/CreateGroupFolder.1.html

Comment: Or on some machines, you could use the URL x-man-page://CreateGroupFolder